# How to add two functions in one onClick method?

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

The code below is an `onClick()` method for a Button.
It keeps giving me an error.
If I delete the `startActivity()`, then it works fine.

How can I use a POST method when I click the Button, and also move to another Activity?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
            if (!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter user information!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
            new HttpAsyncTask().execute(herokuServer);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FoodPreference.class));
            break;
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(Register1Activity.this, FoodPreference.class));
}
```

> THE ERROR:
>       04-27 19:41:26.066    1974-1974/com.opshun_test.opshun_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.opshun_test.opshun_test, PID: 1974
>           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.opshun_test.opshun_test/com.opshun_test.opshun_test.FoodPreference}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
>               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
>               at com.opshun_test.opshun_test.Register1Activity.onClick(Register1Activity.java:173)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   04-27 19:41:26.106    1974-2307/com.opshun_test.opshun_test I/output﹕ org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@5b541ce

Comment: By ERROR, I mean when I click the button, it will stop the application.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Could you post stacktrace for it?

Comment: So "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?" :)

Comment: Oh, I think I found the problem. LOL, the name in Menifest is different from my class name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anonymous inner class for the click listener , use className.this instead of this

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class));
            }
        });
```

if you are handling the click in the activity, make sure the Activity is defined in the manifest file. Provide the stack trace for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare you activity in you manifest. Add the following lines to you manifest file.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FoodPreference"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_food_preference" >
    </activity>
```

Moreover, the more safe way to start an intent is always checking the intent is resolvable or not, like the following code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodPreference.class);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        // TODO: activity not found
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your `Activity` FoodPreference in `Manifest`

and  you are calling

```
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute(herokuServer);
```

So better `Intent` to `FoodPreference.class` in `onPostExecute()`